# jQuery.ajax beforeSend Error in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

this is my code. the result is correct and works in chrome and firefox but in internet explorer i become this error (':' expected) in the beforesend line. this error block my script. i tried with a onload function document.onload and window.onload but it dont fix this problem.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/test',
        beforeSend(xhr){

        },
        success: function (data, textStatus){
            $('#test2').html(data);
        },
        async: true
    });
```

Comment: you need `: function` in there.

Comment: Use the same format as you used for `success` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
 beforeSend(xhr){
 -> change in 
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
```

this solved the problem